# Get Stock Price with PHP & JSON Decode on Google FInance

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents, google-finance

I am trying to retreive the current stock price from Google Finance:

http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=AAPL

How can I extract just the price ("1")?

```
<?php 
$string = file_get_contents("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=AAPL");
$json = json_decode($string, true);
$price = $json["1"];
echo $price;
?>
```

Comment: Print the $json variable in your question

Comment: ...which should answer your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the json returned is commented out, therefore `json_decode()` won't do the business... you need to remove the double slashes - I used [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like this:

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=AAPL");
$arrMatches = explode('// ', $string); // get uncommented json string
$arrJson = json_decode($arrMatches[1], true)[0]; // decode json
$price = $assJson["l"];
echo $price;
```

oh, and the key is a lowercase L (l) not a numeric one (1) in the json

Comment: oh my.dont regex when you dontr have to. `substr($string, 3);`

Comment: @Martijn, you can take the programmer out of perl, but you can't take the  perl out of a programmer! updated to explode() over preg_match()

Comment: Nope, dont want that either. Array functions where simple string functions uffice is also a no go ;) substr really is the one you wanty

Answer (score 0):

The "$arrJson = json_decode($arrMatches[1], true)[0];" line doesn't work because "$arrJson" is empty after it has been executed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).